# JQuery Unslider plugin issue

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to implement Unslider JQuery plugin to my About page. I followed instructions from this website http://unslider.com/ and implemented the plugin but I have two issues that I cannot solve properly:

1. If you look carefully a bit of the text that slides on About section is missing (to the left and to the right side) and it is not position in the very center of the page (it actually is position a bit to the right of the center for some reason???). If I add `.banner {position: relative; left: -25px;}` to my css it looks good on 1366x768 resolution screen but as it is supposed to be responsive and look good on all resolution screens I tried to lower screen resolution by dragging my browser width to less than 1366 and again it doesn't look good and the text parts are missing. So clearly my solution for CSS is not good.
2. I added Prev/Next buttons but they don't show up at all?

Hope you guys can help me! Thanks all :)

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uNKmz/35/

Also, is it possible to change the height of the slider and how do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem to the first question. There was padding given to the `.banner ul` element. Keep in mind that whenever you create a `<ul>` element default padding will be assigned to that element. So all you have to do is assign `padding: 0px` to that specific element so it won't move to the right.

I believe the Unslider people made a typo in the css code which might have confused some people. I believe there should be a style for `.banner ul` not `.banner li` because the list items in the banner already have a style under `banner ul li`.

This is what I changed in the css.

I deleted

```
.banner li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

and added

```
.banner ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Here is the link to the updated fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/theMugician/uNKmz/47/

Comment: Thank you for your reply Grzes! In the meantime I found another solution. I actually used BX Slider which worked fine. However, I see that your solution is working properly and now I can use the Unslider in the future. That's great! Thanks again!